# Cassandra service startup delays with WARN message "min_index_interval of 128 is too low" while reading SSTables in system.log file

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

We found a delay of 2 hrs in starting the Cassandra service with WARN in the system.log file for one table.
Please find the warnings in a few of the below servers:
WARN [SSTableBatchOpen:5] 2022-08-29 10:01:13,732 IndexSummaryBuilder.java:115 - min_index_interval of 128 is too low for 5511836446 expected keys of avg size 64; using interval of 185 instead

Comment: Voted to have this moved to dba.stackexchance.com

Answer (score 2):

Aaron's answer pointed to the right code: Since you have a LOT of keys in a single SSTable, the default `min_index_interval` is not efficient anymore and Cassandra recomputes it. This then triggers a rewrite of the index summary during startup, and in this very case it's taking a very long time.
Aaron's suggestion of using `sstablesplit` would be a temporary fix as eventually they'll get compacted again and you'll be back to the same situation.

Changes will have to be made in production to remediate anyway, and changing the `min_index_interval` seems easy enough as a fix, while really being the only thing to do that won't require deep schema changes to reduce the number of partitions per sstable (or compaction strategy changes which could have hard to predict performance impacts).

Note that changing the `min_index_interval` will not trigger the rewrite of the sstables straight away. Only newly written sstables will get the new setting, which can be (and should be) forced onto all the sstables using `nodetool upgradesstables -a`.

On a side note, there seem to be a confusion in the comments between the partition index and secondary indexes (indices?). They are two distinct things and the reported warning message is referring to the partition index summary, not secondary indexes.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to discern a question from the above, so I'll assume you're wondering why Cassandra is taking 2 hours to start up.

If you look in the source of Cassandra 3.0, there are some clues given in the [IndexSummaryBuilder](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.0/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/sstable/IndexSummaryBuilder.java) class.  Specifically, the calculations just prior to the warning:

```
if (maxExpectedEntriesSize > Integer.MAX_VALUE)
{
    // that's a _lot_ of keys, and a very low min index interval
    int effectiveMinInterval = (int) Math.ceil((double)(expectedKeys * expectedEntrySize) / Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    maxExpectedEntries = expectedKeys / effectiveMinInterval;
    maxExpectedEntriesSize = maxExpectedEntries * expectedEntrySize;
    assert maxExpectedEntriesSize <= Integer.MAX_VALUE : maxExpectedEntriesSize;
    logger.warn("min_index_interval of {} is too low for {} expected keys of avg size {}; using interval of {} instead",
                minIndexInterval, expectedKeys, defaultExpectedKeySize, effectiveMinInterval);
```

The comment about "`that's a _lot_ of keys`" is a big one, and `5,511,836,446` keys is certainly a lot.

The calculations shown in the method above are driven by the number of keys and sampling intervals for a particular SSTable, to build the Partition Summary into RAM.  You can see the Partition Summary on the right side of the diagram showing Cassandra's read path below:

[image]

Based on this, I would hypothesize that one particular table's SSTable file(s) is getting too big to handle efficiently.  Have a look at the underlying data directory for that table.  You may have to [split](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/tools/sstable/sstablesplit.html) some of those files with `tools/bin/sstablesplit` to make them more manageable.

Comment: DSE 5.1.17 is the version

Comment: but this is observed in some of the nodes in the cluster

Comment: and one more thing was observed the timestamp of big-Summary.db is changed for which it is building indexes while startup and only few nodes in cluster is taking time to start the service

Comment: @suraj1287 There was a bug introduced into 4.0-alpha which forced a rebuild of secondary indexes at startup.  I don't know how that would have found its way into DSE 5.1, though.  Your best option here might be to open a support ticket.

Comment: Yes, raised a ticket, but the solution I got is to alter the table with min_index_interval=256, which is not possible as this issue arises in a few of the nodes in the cluster, and I cant alter it in production. Is there any better solution than this

Comment: There seem to be a confusion here between the partition index and secondary indexes (indices?). They are two distinct things and the reported warning message is referring to the partition index summary, not secondary indexes.
There are too many distinct keys in a specific sstable for the default min_index_interval. Aaron's suggestion of using sstablesplit would only be a temporary fix as eventually they'll get compacted again and you'll be back to the same situation.
Changes will have to be made in production to remediate anyway, and changing the min_index_interval seems easy enough as a fix

Comment: Thanks for jumping in on this one and adding some clarity, @AlexanderDEJANOVSKI !  If you could, post your comment as an answer, as yours makes the most sense.

Comment: sure thing, I'll do that